# XAML Path Reused by Multiple DrawingBrush

Tags: xaml

This shouldn't be so hard, but that's XAML for you.  If I have this path:

```
<Path x:Key="SomeShape" Data="..." />
```

How can I reference it in a DrawingBrush (I am constrained to use DrawingBrushes):

```
<DrawingBrush>
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource SomeBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource SomeShape_Nope}">
            <!--Just put the path here dammit -->
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: So from the looks of it, you're just trying to insert PathGeometry.Figures? Is it a single PolyLineSegment with points, or what? Without everything it's hard to say. Are you just looking for something like [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DrawingBrush.aspx)?

Comment: It is figures.  I can't declare a PolyLineSegment with points (just get error "invalid value") and if I declare a PathGeometry with figures I can't reference that from any other element.